# Getting separate PHP variables using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, variables

My **script.js** performs a request to **get_all.php** which has three variables to output (echo) `$all_categories`, `$all_brands` and `$all_filters`. Now I want to manipulate these in three different areas in my **index.html**.

I want to place `$all_categories` in `<div id="caregories">`, `$all_brands` in `<div id="vrands">` and `$all_filtesr` in `<div id="filters">`.

How can I place them separately in each `div` ? I know how to place all of them in one `<div>` but have no idea how to place each variable, received, separately.

**index.php**

```
<?php // Startup ?>

<?php 

    define('APP_PATH', '../');
    define('SYS_PATH', '../system/');
    define('STYLES', 'assets/styles/');
    define('SCRIPTS', 'assets/scripts/');

    require_once SYS_PATH . 'initializers/all.php'; 

?>

<?php // Controller ?>

<?php



?>

<?php // Viewer ?>

<?php template('header'); ?>

<body>

<div id="static_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#categories">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#brands">Brands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#filters">Filters</a></li>
        <li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="categories">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="brands">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="filters">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="social">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>

</body>

<?php template('footer'); ?>
```

**script.js**

```
// DOM ready
$(function(){

    // get categories, brands, filters and social
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_all.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        // manipulate recieved in three different divs
    })

});
```

**get_all.php**

```
<?php // Startup ?>

<?php 

    define('APP_PATH', '../');
    define('SYS_PATH', '../system/');
    define('STYLES', 'assets/styles/');
    define('SCRIPTS', 'assets/scripts/');

    require_once SYS_PATH . 'initializers/all.php'; 

?>

<?php // Controller ?>

<?php

$result_arr = $category->select_all();
$all_categories = $html->list_anchor_loop($result_arr, 'category');
echo $all_categories

$result_arr = $brand->select_all();
$all_brands = $html->list_anchor_loop($result_arr, 'brand');
echo $all_brands;

$result_arr = $filter->select_all();
$all_filters = $html->list_anchor_loop($result_arr, 'filter');
echo $all_filters;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have your PHP script send the result as a JSON object (see [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

In your JS, you'll receive an object, say `resp`, which will have three properties, `resp.categories`, `resp.filters` and `resp.brands`

For more details and specificity, post some code.

In `get_all.php` :

```
$result = array(
  'categories' => $all_categories,
  'brands' => $all_brands,
  'filters' => $all_filters
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

In `script.js`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_all.php",
    dataType : 'json', //specify that data will be returned as JSON
}).done(function(data){
    // use data.categories, data.brands, data.filters here
    // manipulate recieved in three different divs
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If your ajax call returns through [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), it is quiet easy to insert the data into the divs you need:

PHP

```
<?php
$return = array(
    'categories'=>$all_categories,
    'vrands'=>$all_brands,
    'filters'=>$all_filters
    );
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($return).')';?>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("URL_TO_PHP?jsoncallback=?",{
    /*DATA TO SEND*/
    },function(response){
        $('#categories').html(response.categories);
        $('#vrands').html(response.vrands);
        $('#filters').html(response.filters);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a library that does that automatically, like http://phery-php-ajax.net you may pass JSON data directly from PHP while still manipulating the DOM in order. Phery doesn't work with URLs, but with function callbacks, and you may assign to the DIVs from inside PHP itself, like in your case:

```php
<?php

Phery::instance()->set(array(
    'get_all' => function($data){
       /* globals, initialization, etc*/
       $r = new PheryResponse;
       $result_arr = $category->select_all();
       return 
         $r
         ->jquery('#categories')->html($html->list_anchor_loop($result_arr, 'category'))
         ->jquery('#filter')->html($html->list_anchor_loop($result_arr, 'filter'))
         ->jquery('#brand')->html($html->list_anchor_loop($result_arr, 'brand'));

    }
))->process();
```

Then call the `get_all` function from your DOMReady

```js
$(function(){
  phery.remote('get_all');
});
```

Done, everything gets filled for you, without any extra client-side code.